# generating dependent state select box based on country select box in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am developing a mobile-based data entry form in IONIC 4.
I tried to generate states based on the country select box, but its showing errors on generation.

```
code of HTML file
  <ion-item>
        <ion-label>State</ion-label>
        <ion-select (ionChange)="setDistrictValues(sState)" [(ngModel)]="sState" formControlName="sState">
            <ion-select-option [value]="sState" *ngFor="let sState of states">{{sState.name}} </ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="selectedDistricts">
      <ion-label>District</ion-label>
      <ion-select  [(ngModel)]="sDistrict" formControlName="sDistrict">
          <ion-select-option [value]="sDistrict" *ngFor="let sDistrict of selectedDistricts" >{{sDistrict.name}}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

code of page.ts file

```
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private postPvdr: PostProvider,
        private storage: Storage,
        public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        public navController: NavController

      ) { 
        this.initializeState();
        this.initializeDistrict();


      }
      initializeState(){
        this.states = [
            {id: 1, name: 'Melaka'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Johor'},
            {id: 3, name: 'Selangor'}
        ];
        }

        initializeDistrict(){
        this.districts = [
            {id: 1, name: 'Alor Gajah', state_id: 1, state_name: 'Melaka'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Jasin', state_id: 1, state_name: 'Melaka'},
            {id: 3, name: 'Muar', state_id: 2, state_name: 'Johor'},
            {id: 4, name: 'Segamat', state_id: 2, state_name: 'Johor'},
            {id: 5, name: 'Shah Alam', state_id: 3, state_name: 'Selangor'},
            {id: 7, name: 'Klang', state_id: 3, state_name: 'Selangor'}
        ];
        }



        setDistrictValues(sState:any) {

            this.selectedDistricts = this.districts.filter(district => district.state_id == sState.id)

        }
```

its showing error on 
setDistrictValues(sState:any) {

```
            this.selectedDistricts = this.districts.filter(district => district.state_id == sState.id)

        }
```

Comment: **First** of all, don't use ngModel with reactive forms. Use ngModel **or** reactive forms, not both at the same time.

Comment: Also you say you are getting an error, what is the error?

Comment: it's not generating the district select box

Comment: well that is no error.

Comment: can u support me to generate dependable select box from another select box?
ex generating states from the country.

Comment: your code should work for example at least when you use **only** ngModel. As mentioned, you shouldn't mix ngModel and reactive forms. Please create a [mcve], best would be a stackblitz.